# How to count number of occurrences for all different values in database column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a Postgre database that has say 10 columns. The fifth column is called `column5`. There are 100 rows in the database and possible values of `column5` are `c5value1, c5value2, c5value3...c5value29, c5value30`. I would like to print out a table that shows how many times each value occurs.

So the table would look like this:

```
Value(of column5)          number of occurrences of the value
     c5value1                              1
     c5value2                              5
     c5value3                              3
     c5value4                              9
     c5value5                              1
     c5value6                              1
        .                                  .
        .                                  .
        .                                  .
```

What is the command that does that?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Group by the column you are interested in and then use count to get the number of rows in each group:

```
SELECT column5, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY column5
```

Comment: I want to do the same thing. But, instead of columns, I want to count the occurrence of a value in each row ?! how to do it ?

Comment: Is there also a way to just count the one column as in the example you made, but show all columns?

Answer (score 31):

Use the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql/vol1/TheGROUPBYandHAVINGClauses.html) clause and the [`COUNT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function:

```
SELECT column5, COUNT(column5) AS Occurences
FROM myTable
GROUP BY column5
```