# My loop is doubling the results when match is found

Tags: php, loops

I have a database with some months. I am using the following to group similar months:

```
$Mydates = array();
while(........)
{
    $date = $row['date'];
    $Mydates[$date] = (isset($Mydates[$date])) ? $Mydates[$date] + 1: 1;
}
```

My table contains 4 data, 3 Jan's and 1 Feb. Now this information is being run through an array which contains the months of the year. Here is what I have so far:

```
   $months = array("Jan","Feb","Mar",etc........);
    foreach($months as $month)
    {
      foreach($Mydates as $Mydate => $Number)
      {
      if($month == $Mydate)
         {
         echo $month." (".$Number.")<br />";
         }else{
         echo $month."<br />";
         }
      }
    }
```

Now when there were only Jan's this works fine. Now that I have added another month my results display like below:

Jan(3)
Jan(3)
Feb(1)
Feb(1)
Mar
Mar
etc.....
etc.....

How can I get  this to only display once like this:

Jan(3)
Feb(1)
Mar
etc....

Now I have noticed that the more months add the more it duplicates. Can someone look at this and tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: This is because your foreachloop. You will need to break out of it, after a correct match has been found.

Comment: Are you wanting to sum all the numbers for an entire month?

Comment: I agree with Daryl though it would be nice to have had a bit more info.

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense to write your SQL query with a COUNT and a GROUP BY? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866764/how-to-count-number-of-occurences-for-all-different-values-in-database-column?

Comment: @MikePurcell I already did that and for the most of it that part is working fine. My issue is when I am trying to match against the list of months it keeps duplicating the results.

Comment: @ernie I have the dates in the database as unix time stamp so GROUP BY will not work.

Comment: @DarylGill How do you break out of it?

Comment: read the documentation for the full usage of this function

Comment: You should be able to shift this processing to the database, even if you store dates as timestamps. Try using the `DATE_FORMAT` function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, `$Mydates` is already aggregated and accessible by month. Remove the inner loop and just look, if there's a corresponding month in `$Mydates`

```
foreach($months as $month) {
    if(isset($Mydates[$month])) {
        echo $month." (".$Mydates[$month].")<br />";
    } else {
        echo $month."<br />";
    }
}
```