# Count the number of occurrences of a string across multiple attributes in MySQL Database How

Tags: mysql

How can I count the number of occurrences of a string across multiple attributes (in my current case, I have 5 attributes) of a table in a MySQL database? Can I do so using MySQL quer(y/ies)?

The attributes may have NULL values, if that means anything while counting.

Also, I am using PHP on the client-side which I could use if MySQL wouldn't be the better way to find this count, though I want to know how this can be done with MySQL.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866764/how-to-count-number-of-occurences-for-all-different-values-in-database-column), and it's similar to what I want to do, but this solution only works for counting strings over one attribute/column. I need to count the total occurrences of each string over all (e.g.: 5) of my attributes/columns.

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-design your database.  Maybe have a table dedicated to `id, attribute`.

Comment: Table_name(id, attr_1, attr_2, attr_3, attr_4, attr_5) is what I have right now.

Comment: It seems by your question, a value could exist in any of these, so why do you have attributes separated into five columns?

Comment: They're different fields that a user could add the string to from an HTML form. There are a total of five possible fields. The user must put a string (e.g.: with a drop-down) in at least one of the fields (attr_1). The other four attr fields may be NULL (or contain empty strings, haven't figured those details out yet).

Comment: That is just an unusual database structure.  The columns should be something more specific in my opinion.  Otherwise, it would make sense just to use one column for attribute, and multiple rows which would make this query much more simple.

Comment: You're right. I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @string nvarchar(255) = "string" --String to search for

select COUNT(t1.attr_1) + COUNT(t2.attr_2) + COUNT(t3.attr_3) + COUNT(t4.attr_4) + COUNT(t5.attr_5)
from Table_name t
join Table_name t1 on t1.id = t.id
join Table_name t2 on t2.id = t.id
join Table_name t3 on t3.id = t.id
join Table_name t4 on t4.id = t.id
join Table_name t5 on t5.id = t.id
where t1.attr_1 = @string
and t2.attr_2 = @string
and t2.attr_3 = @string
and t2.attr_4 = @string
and t2.attr_5 = @string
```

Comment: This query counts the total number of occurrences of `@string` across the 5 columns. Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly. Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, you didn't understand my question properly, but Devon got me to my solution in the comment-thread above. Thanks anyways!